# Sonata user bundle, with /profile show error

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I'm using Sonata-Admin, Sonata-User and FOSUser. The admin panel works fine, but after the login of an user they are redirected to the route `/profile` with following error:

> An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template
>   ("Using "null" for the value of node "translationBundle" of
>   "Sonata\CoreBundle\Twig\Node\TemplateBoxNode" is not supported. You
>   must pass a Twig_Node instance.") in
>   "SonataUserBundle:Profile:show.html.twig".

Someone know how to repair it ?

Comment: Ok I have solution. For me that was dependency between varsion of bundles. I just change twig/twig to 1.28 .